# C# Cast Error (DataRow)

Tags: c#, mysql, casting, datatable, datarow

I'm working in a website. I can't convert a number value that is in **row[""]** in my Table. My code is:

```
public partial class bought : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected int id;
    protected DataRow row;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["admin"] == null || (bool)Session["admin"] == false) //si es que no eres admin, vete de la pagina porque hay paginas que solo admin puede ver.
        {
            Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
        }
        if (Request.Form["id"] != null)
        {
            id = int.Parse(Request.Form["id"]);
        }
        string sql = "";
        int quantity = int.Parse(Request.Form["quantity"]);
        DataTable dt = DAL.GetTable("select * from item where id =" + id);
        row = dt.Rows[0];
        int realQuantity = (int)row[5];
        int finalQuantity = realQuantity - quantity;
        OleDbConnection con = DAL.GetConnection();
        con.Open(); //ya esta listo, entonces abrimos el Database
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) //si la conexion esta abierta...
        {
            if (realQuantity == quantity)
            {
                sql = "DELETE FROM item WHERE (id =" + id + ")";
            }
            else if (realQuantity > quantity)
            {
                sql = "UPDATE item SET quantity = " + finalQuantity + " WHERE (id = "+id+")";
            }
            OleDbCommand cmd = DAL.GetCommand(con, sql);
            int num = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //es insert y no select. NonQuery es que no devuelve.
            con.Close();
        }
        else Response.Redirect("buyItems.aspx?err=Error en la base de datos");
        Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
    }
}
```

When I run the code(and I also do debugging) the error is here:

*An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App_Web_mavjxnn0.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.*

So the problem is casting a value in a column and in a specific row. **Why can't I cast in that way?**
I have a column that is "quantity", so I tried also to `int realQuantity = (int)row["quantity"];`

Comment: Can you see what value actually is in the `row["quantity"]`

Comment: The danger of using the asterisk to select fields are never fully explained. Are you sure that the 6 column returned by your query is really the "Quantity" column? Of course this assuming that you have really an integer datatype in your db for this column and not something that cannot be converted to an integer.

Comment: This is my dt DataTable: http://i.imgur.com/9mlwbfM.png

Comment: According to the image you don't have a problem. But of course you do, so try what Fabio suggested: check the value of `row["quantity"]` in the debugger. Also take Steve's advice: your code is very fragile if you do a `SELECT *` and then pull column values by index rather than name - I can almost guarantee this will break in the future.

Comment: what is the data type of `quantity` column in database?

Comment: I suppose that this is the way to check. I changed just a bit the code so I can just see what's the value of the row["quantity"]. http://i.imgur.com/qAVGK3g.png

Comment: @PichiWuana It seems the value is `string` and not `int`

Comment: @Magnus thanks for the idea, now I could solve it! I converted it to string the object, and then used int.Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to **System.Data.DataSetExtensions** in your project and try this code to get a value of a named field.

```
using System.Data;

...

row.Field<int>("MyColumnName");
```

Check the correct type of your column (INT => int) and if there are nullable data.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But... How can I do for people to know that this question is already solved (in this case was in the comments)?